# Write statements in Java reads two integers and displays even numbers between them

Tags: java

Write statements that can be used in a Java Program two integers and display the number of even integers that lie between them. For example, the number of even integers that lie between 12 and 5 are 4

So far below is what i have.... the program outputs all the numbers between the two integers, and not the actual number of even integers.

Can someone please help / tell me what i am doing wrong ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class evenNumberPrinter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the smaller integer");
        int numOne = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the larger integer");
        int numTwo = keyboard.nextInt();

        for (int i = numOne; i <= numTwo; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check the number for even/odd before you print.

Comment: @Lashane It doesn't work as the expected result is non-inclusive e.g. between 2 and 3 (3-2+1)/2 = 1.

Answer (score 1):

to calculate count of even numbers you don't have to use for loop, here is the formula:

```
static long evenCount(long a, long b) {
    return ((Math.abs(a - b) + 1) >>> 1) + ((~((a & 1) | (b & 1))) & 1);
}
```

some clarification:

1. zero (0) is even number
2. count of even numbers obviously depends on distance between two values, lets pull some data:

```
0-0 - 1 number, distance 0 (0)
0-1 - 1 number, distance 1
0-2 - 2 numbers, distance 2 (0, 2)
0-3 - 2 numbers, distance 3
0-4 - 3 numbers, distance 4 (0, 2, 4)
0-5 - 3 numbers, distance 5
0-6 - 4 numbers, distance 6 (0, 2, 4, 6)
1-1 - no even, distance 0
1-2 - 1 number, distance 1 (2)
```

so, count of even numbers is determined by `(distance+1)/2` plus one if both numbers are even

so, if we take distance `Math.abs(a-b) + 1` divide it by two (`>>>1`) and then add `1` if and only if both numbers are even `(a&1)==0`

Answer (score 0):

**Edited** to include explanation

Your for loop is doing nothing more than printing each number between `numOne` and `numTwo`. What you want to do is check to see if `i` is even or odd which can be accomplished using the [modulus operator](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html) if `i` modulus 2 equals zero, then that number is even, and you should increment a counter variable each time this is true.

Change your for loop to something like this:

```
int evenCounter = 0;
for (int i = numOne; i < numTwo; i++){
    if (i % 2 == 0){
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        evenCounter++;
    }
}
System.out.println("There are " + evenCounter + " even numbers between " +
                                                numOne + " and " + numTwo);
```

Comment: A code dump without explanation is hardly worth anything.

Comment: @user1803551 At the very least it gives them a working example that he/she will most likely analyze and gain a better understanding of how/why it works.

Comment: But the OP is specifically asking "*what i am doing wrong ?*", so if you intend to post an answer at least include an actual answer - say what you are doing right that the OP is doing wrong.

Comment: @user1803551 I see where you are coming from. I will be sure to do this from now on.

Comment: @user1803551 clever link

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use pure math:

- round the smaller number to the next even number (e.g. 5 to 6)
- round the bigger number to the previous even number (e.g. 13 to 12)
- subtract from the bigger rounded the smaller, e.g. 12-6 = 6
- since even numbers are every second, divide it by 2 plus add one to count the first number of the range as well, that is 3+1=4

That is:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final int number1=1;
    final int number2=6;

    int min=Math.min(number1, number2);
    int max=Math.max(number1, number2);

    min=min+min%2; // round up
    max=max-max%2; // round down

    final int evens=(max-min)/2+1; // even range plus the first number

    System.out.println(evens); // Look ma, no loops
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little more optimal solution (if you want to print the numbers).  Testing for parity (odd vs even) can be done only once, before entering the loop.  Afterwards, just stay on even numbers by incrementing by 2.

```
int n = numOne;
int evenCount = 0;
if ((n%2)==1) { n++; } 
while (n <= numTwo) {
  System.out.println(n);
  n += 2;
  evenCount ++;
}
System.out.println( "There are " + evenCount + " even numbers between " + numOne + " and " + numTwo );
```

However, if your goal is only to determine how many there are (not print them), this is not optimal.  A mathematical solution will be **much** faster.

Answer (score -1):

```
int n = 0; //this is your counter
for (int i = numOne; i < numTwo; i++) { //use < numTwo instead of <= numTwo
//so it doesn't count numTwo as an int between your range
        if (i%2 == 0) {n++;} //checks to see if number is even
// if it is, it adds one to the counter and moves on
    }
System.out.println("there are " +n+ "even numbers between " +numOne+ " and "   +numTwo); //prints out how many even ints were counted.
```

Comment: what is the difference between your answer and Johan's?

Comment: they are very similar, his would print out the even integers and then print out "there are n even numbers between...." mine doesn't print out the even numbers

Comment: A code dump without explanation is hardly worth anything.